# Entity Framework 7 IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to store a large amount of user data in a database where every user already has an ID as a key. However, these users all out of a larger pool of users, therefore, the ID does not increment and cannot be automatically generated. I need to be able to manually set the ID.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you have related data that references those IDs as well?  Either way, it doesn't sound like EF is the right tool for the job - consider using an ETL tool or scripting out the corresponding INSERT statements.

Comment: Can't you just go into the .edmx file and set SoreGeneratedPattern for that Property to "none"?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dave I don't think EF7 uses edmx files

Comment: Well, that'll be fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made some tests and this seems to work for me on EF 7.0.0 rc1-final:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

My test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var db = new FooContext())
    {
        var myFoo = new Foo {Id = 1002, Descr = "Test"};
        db.Add(myFoo);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    using (var db = new FooContext())
    {
        var myFoo = db.Foos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1002);
        Console.WriteLine($"id = {myFoo?.Id}, descrip = {myFoo?.Descr}");
    }
}
```

(full program code here: http://pastebin.com/hSs9HZCP)

It correctly inserts and retrieves a record with the specified id and the table has the correct primary key specified.

This is the migration code generated:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Foo",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
        Descr = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Foo", x => x.Id);
    });
```

Comment: If the database field has been configured as an Identity field, setting `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` will not help. The database will still not allow you to provide an identity manually. You need to allow IDENTITY INSERT on the table. Have a look at this blog. http://blog.robertobonini.com/2014/10/09/entity-framework-with-identity-insert/

Comment: @jvanrhyn I see, I had never tried it personally. I'm going to make a quick project and check

Comment: I've made a simple test and it works for me, just the syntax is wrong for EF7 (this was EF6), I'm updating