# Insert ID field into table through Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have data that I am copying from an old table to a new table. I am trying to do this by using C# to pull the old data, fill the new objects and related objects and saving them to the new database. This is working fine but what I would really like to do is preserve the ID/key fields from the old to the new.

I know that if I was doing this with a SQL query I could enable identity_insert. But is there any way to do this via my Entity Framework code?

This is a one time conversion process from the old to the new database.

Comment: If this is a one time data migration why are you using EF? Seems like a t-sql query would be a lot simpler. You can write in whatever you need to do and not be handcuffed by EF.

Comment: There is a lot of sanitizing, clean up and normalizing of the old data that is much easier for me to perform in C#.

Comment: you can turn off the identity insert on table design, run the app you have for this and once completed enable it again or you can take a look at this [Entity Framework 7] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729106/entity-framework-7-identity-insert)