# Entity Framework Core Use Pre-Existing ID Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a lot of users with preset primary keys, is there any way for me to assign these keys at creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had pretty much the same question about 6 months ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729106/entity-framework-7-identity-insert). The solution was for EF7 and should work flawlessly in EF Core.

Next time try to do a bit more research first.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: And sorry I looked but couldn't find anything